# How to preserve the selection while a link dialog is being displayed?

Tags: javascript, selection

I want to insert a link in `contentEditable` with `document.execCommand`. The link is inserted by a user via a modal window. How to preserve and than restore the selection after the user confirms insertion?

There are a couple of answered questions, but they seem to be outdated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save / restore selection on contentEditable AFTER modifying innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236427/save-restore-selection-on-contenteditable-after-modifying-innerhtml)

Comment: Look for answers given by Tim Down on this website. They will help you solve all your [tag:contenteditable] problems.