# jquery color picker Spectrum not working on Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, contenteditable

I am using [Spectrum](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/) as a jquery plugin for the color picker to use it in the contenteditable divs. In chrome and firefox its working perfectly. But in Internet explorer its just showing the color palettes but when I select nothing is changed.

However, if I exectute `execCommand` directly in this way it is working:

```
$('#btn-color_font').click(function() {
    document.execCommand('foreColor', false, "#ff0000");
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help me how to use it in IE too. Thank you.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karlss/fxfrub5k/)

snippet html:

```
<li class="main-btn">
    <a href="#" id="btn-color_font" class="wysiwyg-color-spectrum-cF">cF</a>
</li>
<li class="main-btn" >
    <a href="#" id="btn-color_background" class="wysiwyg-color-spectrum-bF">cB</a>
</li>
```

snippet js:

```
$(".wysiwyg-color-spectrum-cF").spectrum({
    showPaletteOnly: true,
    togglePaletteOnly: true,
    togglePaletteMoreText: 'more',
    togglePaletteLessText: 'less',
    color: 'blanchedalmond',
    change: function (color) {
        document.execCommand('foreColor', false, color.toHexString());
    },
    hideAfterPaletteSelect: true,
    palette: [
        ["#000", "#444", "#666", "#999", "#ccc", "#eee", "#f3f3f3", "#fff"],
        ["#f00", "#f90", "#ff0", "#0f0", "#0ff", "#00f", "#90f", "#f0f"],
        ["#f4cccc", "#fce5cd", "#fff2cc", "#d9ead3", "#d0e0e3", "#cfe2f3", "#d9d2e9", "#ead1dc"],
        ["#ea9999", "#f9cb9c", "#ffe599", "#b6d7a8", "#a2c4c9", "#9fc5e8", "#b4a7d6", "#d5a6bd"],
        ["#e06666", "#f6b26b", "#ffd966", "#93c47d", "#76a5af", "#6fa8dc", "#8e7cc3", "#c27ba0"],
        ["#c00", "#e69138", "#f1c232", "#6aa84f", "#45818e", "#3d85c6", "#674ea7", "#a64d79"],
        ["#900", "#b45f06", "#bf9000", "#38761d", "#134f5c", "#0b5394", "#351c75", "#741b47"],
        ["#600", "#783f04", "#7f6000", "#274e13", "#0c343d", "#073763", "#20124d", "#4c1130"]
    ]
});
```

Comment: why not to use this : http://www.ajaxtoolkit.net/ColorPicker/ColorPicker.aspx   ???

Comment: Interesting issue... As long as you click on a colour in IE, text selection disappears—thus there isn't text to change any more. Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778508/contenteditable-div-loses-selection-when-another-input-focuses

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Ok, I will look into that. Thanks.

Comment: @Stranger I am sorry, but I think that is a totally different context.

Comment: @Karl I know it is different, But just as a suggestion to working with an easy color picker without any difficulty.

Comment: @Stranger Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that IE is losing the focus/selection before you click in the color, and that's why it's not working. It triggers the `change` event, but since there is nothing selected, nothing happens.

As a workaround, you must save the selection when the Spectrum buttons are clicked, and then restore that selection when the `change` event of Spectrum is triggered.

Something like that:

```
var WinSelection = (function(w, d) {
  var currentSelection = null; // create a variable to save the current selection

  function saveSelection() { // saveSelection copied from another SO answer
    if (w.getSelection) {
      sel = w.getSelection();
      if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
        return sel.getRangeAt(0);
      }
    } else if (d.selection && d.selection.createRange) {
      return d.selection.createRange();
    }
    return null;
  }

  function restoreSelection(range) { // restoreSelection copied from another SO answer
    if (range) {
      if (w.getSelection) {
        sel = w.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
      } else if (d.selection && range.select) {
        range.select();
      }
    }
  }

  return { // return an object with two public methods: saveSelection and restoreSelection
    saveSelection: function() {
      currentSelection = saveSelection();
    },
    restoreSelection: function() {
      restoreSelection(currentSelection);
    }
  };
})(window, document);
```

Then, in your code, you can save the selection when the buttons are clicked:

```
$('#wysiwyg-editor li a').click(function() {
  WinSelection.saveSelection();
});
```

And inside your `change` event, you restore the selection:

```
/* ... */
change: function (color) {
  WinSelection.restoreSelection();
  document.execCommand('foreColor', false, color.toHexString());
},
/* ... */
change: function (color) {
  WinSelection.restoreSelection();
  document.execCommand("BackColor", false, color.toHexString());
},
/* ... */
```

And here is [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fxfrub5k/1/) - updated, and working in IE.

Comment: Was away for sometime. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Wanting to offer another solution that had worked for me:

Add the html attribute `unselectable='on'` to these three divs that will be generated by the spectrum plugin (I executed the code after the site had finished loading):

```
jQuery(".sp-replacer").attr("unselectable", "on");
jQuery(".sp-preview").attr("unselectable", "on");
jQuery(".sp-preview-inner").attr("unselectable", "on");
```

This prevents losing the focus on the selected text. From my tests, this shouldn't influence normal behavior in other browsers (tested on Firefox, Chrome and Opera).
Edit: Simple color selection works, but if I want to select a predefined color or enter another value by hand into the displayed input field, the selection is still lost.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add proprietary filters for IE to get gradient support

Checkout: http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#details-ieImplementation