# WYSIWYG Editor place HTML content in current position

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, rich-text-editor

I am using a WYSIWYG Rich Text Editor from [mindmup](https://github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg)

I added a dropdown box in toolbar I use this dropdown to fetch the content from server and append/prepend to the existing content in the Editor where the cursor is pointing.

[image]

But it is not adding the data to the editor.

I referred [Insert html at caret in a contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690752/insert-html-at-cursor-in-a-contenteditable-div) and [Insert text at cursor in a content editable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920150/insert-text-at-cursor-in-a-content-editable-div)

But they are not working for me.

This is the function i used to fetch the data when changing drop down

```
function loadJournalTemplate(journalTemplateId) {

$.post('/Journal/GetTemplate', { journalId: journalTemplateId }, 
  function (data, textStatus) {
    if (textStatus == "success") {

        $('#editor1').html(data.content); //Here i need to append/prepend
    }
 }, "json");

}
```

How can we add HTML at a current cursor position?

Note: This [Insert text at cursor in a content editable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920150/insert-text-at-cursor-in-a-content-editable-div) adds the content in dropdown itself, when I directly choose a dropdown before clicking editor

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the toolbar buttons are stealing the focus from the editable element, thus destroying the selection. You'll either need to prevent the buttons/dropdowns from doing this or [save and restore the cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6727472/96100), in which case you'll need to detect clicks on the toolbar buttons before they destroy the selection (possibly using `mousedown`).

Example: [contenteditable selected text save and restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687808/contenteditable-selected-text-save-and-restore/4690057#4690057)